# Cors policy in .net, siganlr and mauk

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr

I am trying to add core police to my SignalR.

```
builder.Services.AddCors(x => { 
    x.AddPolicy("signalr_policy",x=>x.WithOrigins("https://domain1","https://domain1","https://domain2","https://domain3", "https://www.domain1", "https://www.domain2","https://www.domain3", "https://www.domain4", "https://localhost"));});
```

```
[EnableCors("signalr_policy")]
public class Services:Hub
{
}
```

My opinion is that I should have access to that SignalR...
I've tried but I get an error saying I can't access bce of core policy.
I would like to have access via my MAUI application as well.

Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: What is the exact protocol and host of your client app where you see the cors error message? And is this added to your WithOrigins() call? - I can see 'httpS://localhost' and I guess your client is running on http://localhost (without s)?

Comment: well i see it from the other domains.
well localhost i remove.. but didnt help

405
Method Not Allowed

Comment: https://object.social/
see the network then you will see

Answer (score 0):

```
builder.Services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("corsapp", builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
}));
```

```
app.UseCors("corsapp");
```

so thats it for me